# Hay alguna manera de sacar un dato en especifico de una tabla de atributo enum por medio de php?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestion es que requiero sacar el tipo ->Admin,para luego guardarla en una variable,gracias de antemano.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es lo que he intentado

Comment: Necesitas agregar lo que hayas intentado y las imágenes no son estrictamente necesarias, puedes hacer un select * from esaTabla y colocar la salida como texto

Comment: gracias, ya agrego como lo estoy planteando.

Comment: Insisto por favor el código como texto